# When I try to "link Stack Exchange account" in Stack Overflow Careers 2.0, I get an error

Tags: support, jobs, linked-accounts, error-message, redirection

When I try to "link stack exchange account" in Stack Overflow Careers 2.0, I get an error in Chrome on Mac OSX 10.7.5. The error reads "website has a redirect loop" and the website doesn't show up. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try logging out from Stack Overflow first. If no luck try different browser.